# CURL or file_get_contents to update a list of feeds?

Tags: php, curl, rss, file-get-contents

I am running a feed reader site, where there will be a lot of RSS around. I will have to synchronize those feeds as often as possible, so I found these two methods of doing it.

**1 method : Using CURL**

```
$weblog_name = 'MyBlog';
$weblog_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/myblog';
$ping_url = 'http://ping.feedburner.com';

$request = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>weblogUpdates.ping</methodName>
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>$weblog_name</string>
  </value>
 </param>
 <param>
  <value>
   <string>$weblog_url</string>
  </value>
 </param>
</params>
</methodCall>
EOT;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ping_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($request)); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Second Method : file_get_contents**

```
file_get_contents("http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/pingSubmit?bloglink=http://feeds.feedburner.com/myblog");
```

My question is which is the better and faster solution to ping at least 50 feeds at once ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fetching google.com using file_get_contents took (in seconds):

```
2.31319094
2.30374217
2.21512604
3.30553889
2.30124092
```

CURL took:

```
0.68719101
0.64675593
0.64326
0.81983113
0.63956594
```

This was using the benchmark class from http://davidwalsh.name/php-timer-benchmark

Answer (score 3):

Because you will be updating 50 feeds *at once*, I would strongly suggest using CURL for two reasons:

1. you can use curl_multi() functions that will allow you to send
   all 50 requests at once, while file_get_contents() will only go
   one-by-one. The documentation for these functions is a bit sparse,
   so I would suggest using a lightweight library - it's much easier to
   work with. I personally use
   https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl, but you will find many
   around.
2. as you are pinging the services, you do not really need to know
       the response, I guess (as long as it's HTTP 200). So you could
   use
       the CURL option CURLOPT_NOBODY to make it into a HEAD request,
   thus
       in response you would get the headers only, too. This should
   speed
       up the process even more.

Put it otherwise, file_get_contents might be faster for simple requests, but in this case your situation is not simple. Firing 50 requests without really needed to get the whole document back is not a standard request.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i think curl is faster than file_get_contents.

Googling a bit I've found out some benchmarks here in SO: [file_get_contents VS CURL, what has better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend considering using curl ... while it might be some development overhead at first sight, it is much more powerful than file_get_contents. especially if you want to fetch multiple feeds, curl multi requests might be worth looking at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want flexibility for the future (e.g. Authentication, Cookies, Proxy etc.) then use cURL. The speed is about the same as file_get_contents() judging from benchmarks (some say it's faster)

If you want a quick and easy solution then by all means use file_get_contents(). However, it wasn't built for the purpose for requesting external URL's. Most people swear by cURL for doing any work with external URL's, even simple GET requests.

The only additional work with using cURL is a few extra lines of code, wrap it in a function and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

get_file_contents is faster. It does a simple http without any extra instantiations

Comment: I am not familiar with Curl, does it get the contents? I mean how does it work?
Also, will 50 get_file_contents at once be very slow ?

Comment: cURL will get the headers for the http request as well.  
You can add your own request headers, post variables and proxy server in cURL. However, for a simple get request, cURL is unnecessary.
I find cURL takes 10 ms longer on my wamp server apache2.2.17 php5.3.5 for http://www.google.com

Comment: @mtopia it doesn't really make a difference because get_file_contents is synchronous, i.e. the next line is executed only after this line has been completely executed